# How to include client-side script in Jade template?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pug, momentjs

I'm using **jade** to generate a static website written **grunt** and I want to call moment.js from my jade template.

I don't know how I am supposed to load the moment library.

The [official documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/) says:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "moment": "path/to/moment",
    }
});
define(["moment"], function (moment) {
    moment().format();
});
```

But I'm not sure how the async loading works with jade.

So I wrote this code that doesn't compile:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    script(src='scripts/require.js')
    script. 
      require.config({
            paths: {
                "moment": "scripts/moment.js",
            }
      });
  body
    p #{moment(Date.now()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}
```

with the following error:

```
>> TypeError: src/test.jade:7
>>     5|     script. 
>>     6|         require.config({
>>   > 7|             paths: {
>>     8|                 "moment": "scripts/moment.js",
>>     9|             }
>>     10|         });
>> 
>> undefined is not a function
```

**How am I supposed to load my moment object so it can be used in Jade (templates and mixins)?**

> Note if I replace the line p #{moment(Date.now()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')} with p #{Date.now()} it compiles.

Comment: I'm not sure but miss indent is the prime suspect. Jade is the template engine. so you must follow indent and others by Jade's way.

Comment: I tried with different indentation. But to no avail (I updated my question). 
Besides, Jade doesn't need indented javascript, right?

Comment: I have a question about it. Your jade file include requirejs and it call momoentjs. Btw, your last code want to write the function result to html right on the template -> html moment right?

Comment: Yes. I want to write the result of the moment call to the page

Comment: I asked @ForbesLindesay. he said to me about grunt config.
@ForbesLindesay : It needs to be done in your grunt config so it gets passed to jade as a local: `{moment: require(‘moment’)}`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer (it works indeed). Do you have a sample of code to post so I can approve your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to make your javascript available when grunt calls the jade compiler to generate the final html file

> **Note** the ouput of the javascript will be statically copied into the html file. The javascript library is a compile time (devDependency) only dependency.

Simple test file

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
  body
    p #{moment(Date.now()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}
    p Hello guys !!
```

Grunt file

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    ... 
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        ...
        moment = require ('moment') ;
        grunt.registerTask( ...
        ...
```

Package file

```
{
  "name": "site",
   ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "moment": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

> Thanks to @ForbesLindesay for his help